# IBM Ultrium Tape drive shows up but can't mount a tape

Tags: 10.04, server, drive

I have this tape drive install in a dell poweredge 2900 server and I can seem to get it working, ubuntu can see the drive but I cant mount any tape I even Did mt -f /dev/nst0 erase and the drive led started to blink. any suggestions?

Comment: A tape drive?! Wow! That's old!

Comment: yes it is jejeje but I really want this working

Comment: I understand. Unfortanately I don't know much about this topic so I can't help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tape drives are a bit old school , and you manage them with mt and tar.

My guess is that it takes time for the tape to write (with your erase command).

[man mt](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mt)

Rewind the tape

```
mt -f dev/nst0 rewind
```

List files on the tape

```
tar -tzf dev/nst0
```

See also: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-tape-backup-with-mt-and-tar-command-howto/